# How do I get the society card?

Tags: godus

I appear to be missing something obvious. I have expanded quite rapidly and have a population of 2500+ but I appear to be missing the 'society' card and can't work out how to get it:

[image]

How do I get the society card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Society cards are available from a variety of actions, and are usually unlocked once you reach a particular threshold. In general, the methods of getting society cards includ;

- Increasing your population
- Advancing between periods
- Completing multiplayer objectives (Mount of the Gods)
- Getting a certain amount of resources

The card in the screenshot in the question however, society card #13, only appears to be available by taking part in the **Mount of the Gods** event for the first time. This is done by finding an activating the Mount of the Gods shrine:

[image]